# How to pass credential to REST API

Tags: python, rest, get

I am using below python code. But it keep throwing wrong user name or password. Looks like credential are not parsed correctly. But i know credential are correct since it works when i use CURL in DOS command prompt.

```
import requests as re
import json
re.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
url = 'https://nwsppl300p:9090/nwrestapi/v3/global/clients/?q=hostname:BMCJCA001T.corpads.local'
auth = ('cormama.remote\jamal', 'Inventigation100get$pump')
r = re.get(url, auth=auth,verify=False)
print (r.content)
```

Getting message

```
b'{"message":"Unauthorized access: The username or password is incorrect","status":{"code":401,"codeClass":"Client Error","reasonPhrase":"Unauthorized"},"timestamp":"2022-06-17T15:00:14-04:00","userAgentRequest":{"headers":[{"name":"Accept","value":"*/*"},{"name":"Accept-Language"},{"name":"Content-Type"}],"method":"GET","query":"q=hostname:BMCJCA001T.corpads.local","url":"https://nwsppl300p:9090/nwrestapi/v3/global/clients/"},"version":"19.5.0.5.Build.154"}'
```

Comment: What is the '\' you have in the username? Did you intend for that to be a literal '\'?

Comment: cormama.remote\jamal , cormama.remote is domain and jamal is my account.

Comment: can you post the CURL request that is working?

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32>curl -i -X GET -k -u cormama.remote\jamal:Inventigation100get$pump https://nwsppl300p:9090/nwrestapi/v3/global/clients/?q=hostname:BMCJCA001T.corpads.local

Comment: You want either `r'cormama.remote\jamal'` (using a raw string), or `'cormama.remote\\jamal'` (double escape for literal '\'

Comment: It worked with r option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are either providing the wrong creds, or perhaps in the wrong format.

Are you able to access your site in a browser using those credentials?

Do you know how to use Fiddler Classic?

You can use Fiddler to capture the call (turn ON HTTPS encryption) when using the browser and capture that call to understand the format needed. note: if you leave fiddler running when debugging; it is a proxy and may interfere with VScode if you are using that to debug...you can use the following to get proxy certs:

os.environ['CURL_CA_BUNDLE'] = ''

[image]

The example below requires that I POST a json with my creds in order get my auth token. Your site may be different, but you can use this to figure out what it needs specifically.

in the example shown:

```
userName = {"email":"someEmail", "password":"somepass"}
auth = re.post(url, json=userName)
```